# How to install new module in OpenERP 8.0?

Tags: odoo

I copied directory (module) nk_test into /opt/odoo/odoo/addons directory, but when I go to OpenERP Settings/Local Modules (no filter) I can not find the module to install it. I don't know what am I missing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to:

1. Choose "Users" from the menu
2. Click the current user, and edit it by checking "Technical features"
3. Refresh the page
4. Click the "Update module list" menu item.

Answer (score 8):

**If you are using Odoo8.**

First in odoo login and do the following:

1.Go to settings Choose "Users" from the menu
Click the current user, and edit it by checking "Technical features"

2.Refresh the page

3.unpacked the module at ../server/openerp/addons

4.Go to modules under settings and Click the "Update module list" menu item.

5.follow the instructions the app should display under local modules
all the best

**If you are using Odoo 9**

1.Activate the developer mode by doing to About page(by clicking the user profile picture).

2.Go to settings Choose "Users" from the menu
Click the current user, and edit it by checking "Technical features"

3.Refresh the page

4.unpacked the module at ../server/openerp/addons

5.Go to modules under settings and Click the "Update module list" menu item.

6.follow the instructions the app should display under local modules
all the best

Answer (score 2):

**odoo 10**
Activate the developer mode is move to "setting" menu and bottom of the "Share the Love" column.