# Unique email field in Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, unique-constraint, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to set the email from Leads and Contacts unique.

I have tried to change in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py` file, line 342 from:

```
_sql_constraints = []
```

in:

```
_sql_constraints = [
        ('user_email', 'unique(user_email)', 'Please enter Unique Email'),
]
```

But is not working.

What is the right approach, please give me a full example, because I am a beginner in Odoo, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You changed sql constraints on the `BaseModel`. **All models** in the system are based on this model. So the effect of this change is to add the constrain to every model in Odoo, most of which doesn't even have `user_email` field. The result of this could be absolutely disastrous. The only reason your Odoo haven't failed yet is you didn't use the upgrade option, so for now the changes haven't propagate to the database.

First of all revert the changes **immediately**. Second of all you are not supposed to ever change Odoo source code directly. For one thing, if you start modifying Odoo's source code you will never be able to update it to a newer version (even with a security update), since this would revert your changes.

What you should do instead is to [create a new module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html) and then use it to extend the module you want to modify:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    _sql_constraints = [
            ('user_email', 'unique(user_email)', 'Please enter Unique Email'),
    ]
```

**Note:** There was [a bug](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3957) in early versions of Odoo 8 preventing one from changing sql constraints by extending an object. It is now fixed. Make sure you are using the most recent version of Odoo from git. If this is not possible it may be necessary to use [a work around](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/changing-sql-constraints-child-models-odoo-8.html).

Comment: OK, thank you for corrections. I have made the module and still not working after I have add the class in `addons/mymodule/models.py` the version of Odoo is : Odoo Server 8.0-20150916. Do I need to restart service or something?

Comment: You need to create an `__openerp__.py` manifest file for you module, and an `__init__.py` file referencing your models.py file. Then you need to install the module. I strongly recommend reading the article about creating modules: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html

Comment: I have generated the module as described `odoo.py scaffold mymodule addons` and changed the `__openerp__.py` file and added the code for unique email field in `models.py`. How can I install the module, I should see it in `Settings>Modules>Apps` ?

Comment: Ok, that's very good. You should be able to see it after [updating the modules list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27848408/262618).

Comment: Ok done, but still I can add emails that are not unique, the `_sql_constraints` in not good?

Comment: Looks good, but make sure there are no non-unique email records when you install your module. If there are any, Odoo will not be able to add the constraint to postgresql.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90173/discussion-between-ek-kosmos-and-ludwik-trammer).